# Listview previous item disappear on new item addition on button click

Tags: android, listview, button, android-arrayadapter

When I add new item to list view my previous item goes away. It only displays latest item.

I have two editview, name and email. And a button create player. On button click, name and email should add as one item(2 line) in list view.

Please help.

Regards

CreateTeamActivity.java

```
package com.recscores.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CreateTeamActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

    Button addPlayer;
    Button createPlayer;
    LinearLayout view_createPlayer;
    TableLayout numberPad;
    EditText Email;
    EditText Name;
    EditText teamname;
    ListView Roster;

       private CustomAdapter adapter;

    private ArrayList<PlayerInfo> fetch = new ArrayList<PlayerInfo>();


         private  PlayerInfo info = new PlayerInfo();
    private ListView lv;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_team);

    addPlayer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addplayer);
    createPlayer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.createplayer);

    Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);

    lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(CreateTeamActivity.this,
            android.R.id.list,
            fetch);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    createPlayer.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View v) {

          switch(v.getId()){


          case R.id.createplayer: /** Create Player */


              info.SetName(Name.getText().toString());
              info.SetEmail(Email.getText().toString());

            fetch.add(info);

            counter++;
         // lv.invalidateViews();
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //Thread.sleep(2000);



               break;
          }



}


}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.recscores.android;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlayerInfo>{
    private ArrayList<PlayerInfo> entries;
    private Activity activity;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<PlayerInfo> entries) {
        super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
        this.entries = entries;
        this.activity = a;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView item1;
        public TextView item2;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {

        return entries.size();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.add_player_listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.item2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.email);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

        final PlayerInfo custom = entries.get(position);
        if (custom != null) {
            holder.item1.setText(custom.GetName());
            holder.item2.setText(custom.GetEmail());
        }
        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

`PlayerInfo info = new PlayerInfo();`

before

`info.SetName(Name.getText().toString());`

Comment: thanks for replying..  I add it as you suggested. Now the first item I add, remains in the listview.But the new item is not getting added. So there is still one item in the listview and that item is the very first item I add.

Comment: Thanks MaciejGórski ...I got it. In my xml I had Listview inside scrollview which was causing the problem. I removed scrollview and now it is working as I intended.